# Count the number of occurrences of an item in a list without list.count

Tags: python, list, count

I need to know how you can count the number of times an item appears in a list WITHOUT using the `.count()` function. For example, I know that if I have a code that runs as

```
>>> [1,2,3,1,2,1].count(1)
```

then it will output `3`.

To clarify a little, I want to know specifically how I can get that output `3`, without using `.count()`.

Comment: in loop check each element of array and count?

Comment: im not sure how to do that... Can you give code for that please?

Comment: `len([i for i in x if i == 1])`

Comment: what should I set i and x equal to? The elements in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many ways of doing this:

```
x = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
count = len([i for i in x if i == 1])
print count
```

Another way:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(x)
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
>>> counter.get(1)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Okay. So now if I want it to detect a random word, how would I sub in the i == 1 for a random word in a list?

Comment: Just replace `1` with whatever you want to check for. example: `i == 2`

Answer (score 7):

you can use a for loop like this

```
x = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
count = 0
for i in x:
    if i == 3:
        count+= 1
print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
>>> sum(x == 1 for x in lst)
3
>>> sum(1 for x in lst if x == 1) # Alternately
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len([a for a in [1,2,3,1,2,1] if a == 1])
```

Comment: Decent hack, but could do with some explanation.